# Spotipy Audio Features - get track name from uri

Tags: python, spotipy

Spotify's `audio features` `endpoint` returns requests like so:

```
{ audio_features: 
   [ { "danceability": 0.808,
       "energy": 0.626,
       "key": 7,
       "loudness": -12.733,
       "mode": 1,
       "speechiness": 0.168,
       "acousticness": 0.00187,
       "instrumentalness": 0.159,
       "liveness": 0.376,
       "valence": 0.369,
       "tempo": 123.99,
       "type": "audio_features",
       "id": "4JpKVNYnVcJ8tuMKjAj50A",
       "uri": "spotify:track:4JpKVNYnVcJ8tuMKjAj50A",
       "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4JpKVNYnVcJ8tuMKjAj50A",
       "analysis_url": "http://echonest-analysis.s3.amazonaws.com/TR/WhpYUARk1kNJ_qP0AdKGcDDFKOQTTgsOoINrqyPQjkUnbteuuBiyj_u94iFCSGzdxGiwqQ6d77f4QLL_8=/3/full.json?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJRDFEY23UEVW42BQ&Expires=1458063189&Signature=JRE8SDZStpNOdUsPN/PoS49FMtQ%3D",
       "duration_ms": 535223,
       "time_signature": 4 
     },
```

I would like to print tracks names along with a given feature under a condition, like so:

```
features = show_audio_features(artist)

low_energy_songs = [x['energy'] for x in features if x < 0.5]
```

how do I print song **names** + parameters, instead of printing its `url`?

must I make a request to another `endpoint`?

thanks!

Comment: When you retrieve data from the `audio features endpoint` you need to use the `id`. How do get the id?

Comment: the `audio_features` endpoint is based on a list of `tracks`  or `track_id`s, not `artist`s, if you want to use that endpoint, my guess is you'll first need to create a list of artists based on a list of tracks.

Comment: Using the "id" given from the `audio_features` endpoint, you can pass that "id" to the `track` endpoint, `sp.track(track_id)['name']`  which will return you the song name.